# Generating Temporary Credentials with IAM Role from EC2 Instance in aws .net SDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am currently facing an issue while attempting to retrieve temporary credentials using an IAM Role for an EC2 instance in my AWS environment. I'm using the AWS SDK for .NET, here is the error log

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the
> request. Amazon.SecurityToken.AmazonSecurityTokenServiceException:
> Cannot call GetSessionToken with session credentials
> 2023-10-06T13:37:15.567408512Z  --->
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type
> 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.
> 2023-10-06T13:37:15.567411486Z    at
> Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) 2023-10-06T13:37:15.567413696Z    at
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext
> executionContext) 2023-10-06T13:37:15.567415774Z    at
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext
> executionContext) 2023-10-06T13:37:15.567417810Z    at
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext
> executionContext)

here is the code snippet I'm using to try and obtain these credentials:

```
 using var stsClient = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(region);
        var getSessionTokenRequest = new GetSessionTokenRequest
    {
        DurationSeconds = 3600 // seconds
    };
    
    GetSessionTokenResponse sessionTokenResponse =
        await stsClient.GetSessionTokenAsync(getSessionTokenRequest); // error twrown from this line
    
    Credentials credentials = sessionTokenResponse.Credentials;
    
    return credentials;
```

**IAM role is working fine when creating `new AmazonS3Client(region)`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAM roles cannot get session tokens, only users and accounts can.

If you want to retrieve the same credentials as a normal credential resolution chain would (on EC2, they are normally retrieved from the metadata endpoint), you can use [`FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Runtime/MFallbackCredentialsFactoryGetCredentials.html).

It's a static method which will give you the same set of temporary credentials that the rest of AWS SDK clients will be using if constructed without parameters.

If you want to assume another role, or even the same role with duration or policies different from what your EC2 instance was given, then you should call [`AssumeRole`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html).

Comment: Hi Quasssnoi,

I will try this
I have a question about FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(). Will it return temporary AWS access-secret keys, or will it return long-term keys?

My goal is to connect to Snowflake from my .NET project and unload data from Snowflake to S3. Here is the unload query:
COPY INTO 's3://<bucket>/test_data/TEST1'

FROM TESTDB..TEST1

FILE_FORMAT = 'CSVFORMAT'

 CREDENTIALS = (AWS_KEY_ID = '<>'

        AWS_SECRET_KEY = '<>')

Comment: @RaGibNoor: it will return temporary credentials. IAM roles don't have long-term keys. For your use case, it's better to create a role that can only access the S3 bucket, assume it, and pass the credentials returned by `AssumeRole` to Snowflake

Comment: if we get the credentials from FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials()
how can we find out the session token timeout?

Comment: @RaGibNoor: AWS doesn't provide a way to figure out credentials' expiration time (not that I know of, at least) from the credentials. If you explicitly query them from the metadata (that's what `FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials()` does under the hood) by calling the [metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials), it will return you the expiration time as well. Again, the clean way to use IAM for your use case is to create a role for Snowflake and assume it when need be.